# PostgreSQL After docker-compose down the used port cant be used again

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, docker, docker-compose

I am working with a project that uses express as the server and postgres as the db to learn dockers.
the server depends on the db to be up.
The first time i use docker-compose up it all works fine but when i restart it
(docker-compose down and docker-compose up again) it says that something is wrong with the port

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'Donald'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'Aa123456'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'twitter'

  backend:
    build: twitter
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      PGHOST: "db"
      PGPORT: '5432'
      PGDATABASE: 'twitter'
      PGUSER: 'Donald'
      PGPASSWORD: 'Aa123456'
```

The error

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:5432
backend_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
backend_1  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
backend_1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
backend_1  |   syscall: 'connect',
backend_1  |   address: '172.19.0.2',
backend_1  |   port: 5432 }
```

ports before docker-compose down

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b000b9a02257        excer_backend       "node server"            5 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   excer_backend_1
40ca65adcc46        postgres:10         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   excer_db_1
```

after i use docker-compose down and see the ports its all clean and no open ports are left

Than i found something very interesting a when i used docker-compose up it always worked if i use ctr + c and use compose up again still work same when i restart docker but as soon as i use **docker-compose down** the error is shown.
I tried man combinations with restarting my docker and ctr + c and compose-up
all worked but as soon as i use docker-compose down it dosent work why is that ?

Comment: It could be the port is still being used. Check by seeing if the port is still open

Comment: Already checked ports there are none open ports after docker-compose down

Comment: Are you sure `179.19.0.2` is the correct address? Is it possible that the new postgres container has received a different address? You can use the hostname `db` or your environment variable `PGHOSTNAME`. Also postgresql has a bit of a spin up time, so if you start both containers at the same time, you might have to let your application server sleep for a few seconds before attempting to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the DB is not up *yet*.

When you do `docker-compose down`, it deletes the container and since you aren't using a volume for persistence, the DB has to run through its init process again which will take a few seconds (and hence works when you `ctrl+c` and `docker-compose up` again).

Do note that `depends_on` doesn't wait until the DB is up. You will have to using something like [`wait-on`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on) for that in your backend container.

Another solution would be to use a volume mount for the DB container.